# how to install switchyard in JBDS?

Tags: jboss, switchyard

I am getting the error as could not find file while trying to install from main menu help and install new software and adding the appropriate site.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using proxy and if the proxy details are correct. if it fails even with correct proxy. You can try offline install

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/SWITCHYARD/Installing+Eclipse+Tooling